# ios coredata error Can't find model for source store

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data

I added some changes in my data model and now I have that error message:

> Can't find model for source store

Could you explain me what is the reason of this? how to solve this problem? why did it not appear after my previous data model's changes?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You didnt't use version control when migrating to a new model. Before you make changes to your model you need to create a new version so that it knows to track the changes this way.

When I had this issue i tried many different soluyions (including renaming mom to momd and vice versa) and the only thing that worked was to start a new project. Same name, default core data. I built my model first, then i copied pasted all the classes, etc and then spent a few hours making sure it all connected and worked, etc...

Then I learned to use git, starting keeping version control, and started using model versions as well. Now if I run into a deadly error, I go back to the previous version on git and it's like nothing happened.

Good luck